# Understanding how to manage dependencies in a custom npm library

Tags: npm, package.json

I am trying to write my first set of npm libraries for a large, distributed application and am running into problems around how to manage dependencies.  Npm has the concept of "dependencies" and "peerDependencies".

From what I read, `peerDependencies` are needed when you want to write a "plugin" where the consuming application is already expected to have the dependency installed on their end. For example, this might be building a plugin for `webpack`.

Then there are regular dependencies needed at runtime by a library. In my scenario, I am trying to write a library to abstract Authentication and Authorization away from the consuming application.  This new library (lets call it @myapp/auth) has a dependency on the `@auth0/angular-jwt` library as it uses it to deal with JWTs.  I want this library to be **completely** abstracted away from the consuming application and therefore not force that consuming application to install it manually.

With that said, it sounds like I need to add `@auth0/angular-jwt` to `dependencies` in my library and then add it to the `whitelistedNonPeerDependencies` which allows it to build.

This confuses me because the `ng-packagr` [docs say that we should always use `peerDependencies` when possible](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/dependencies.md).  If this is the case, then why when you install a larger library like `express`, you simply run `npm install express --save` and you get **ALL** of the dependencies of `express` without manually installing each one.

What is the proper way to include package dependencies in a custom library that you **do not** want the consuming application to install themselves?